# How to delete first name letters for downloaded files from mail

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i have macro where download all attachments from multiple emails, this code works fine, but I need change code to change every file name where was downloaded in folder, files name like "I10001258", "I10003256", "I10004758"... I wanna delete **first five letters** "**I1000**1258", for all downloading files. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Attachments()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fo As Outlook.Folder
Dim at As Outlook.Attachment

Set fo = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Your Mail Box Name Here").Folders("Inbox").Folders("My Report")

Dim lr As Integer

For Each msg In fo.Items
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = msg.Subject
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = msg.Attachments.Count

    For Each at In msg.Attachments
       If VBA.InStr(at.Filename, ".xls") > 0 Then
            at.SaveAsFile sh.Range("F1").Value & "\" & at.Filename
       End If
    Next
    
Next
 
MsgBox "Reports have been downloaded successfully"



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mid()` can be used to skip the first characters.

> ```
>  at.SaveAsFile sh.Range("F1").Value & "\" & Mid(at.Filename, 6)
> ```

[image: Immediate Window Result]

Comment: So this method is better that =RIGHT (Text, LEN(text)-N) function?

Comment: @PowerCat 6 of 1 half a dozen of the other.  I think it is simpler.

Comment: Because in job, they disabled index search, and I wanna make my self simpler using search in folder like 3256 OR 3247 OR ... Because now I need write always I10003256 OR I10003247 OR... Maybie you have another better idea :)

Comment: @PowerCat Gotcha, it really comes down to user preference.  For consistency ,consider have a dedicated function to create the filename.

Comment: I cant create specifics names, because I need print documents in a row from white paper where are these codes, like 3256, 3247. But very thanks, I will try use MID function.

Comment: have one more little question, how to make in msgbox to write how much files downloaded? Count

Comment: @PowerCat `MsgBox msg.Attachments.Count & " Reports have been downloaded successfully"` should do it.

Comment: but problem with MID function, that, all files all goode show name what i need, but all files loses their file formats :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243041/discussion-between-tinman-and-power-cat).